# "Share" link doesn't really link question

Tags: bug, answers, questions, hyperlinks

When inserting a "short permalink" (i.e., the one obtained by clicking the "share" link) into a question or an answer, as clear text, it is substituted by the question title:

[Do we like the share buttons? Do people use them?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/757/8057)

However, the question doesn't appear in the list of "linked question" -- only if I use the explicit URL, in this case, `https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/757/do-we-like-the-share-buttons-do-people-use-them`.

Is this a bug or a feature? As I understand it, the "short permalink" is tied to my user account, and each click counts. So I'd like to use these permalinks, but I find the "linked question" feature more important.

**EDIT**: Actually, at least here on Meta, the question eventually appears as "linked". Perhaps I am just too impatient, but I have the impression that this happens faster on StackOverflow.

Comment: Just a note: links within the network don't count and aren't tracked...so the user portion of the URL doesn't mean much here.

Answer (score 6):

There is a clear distinction between the when the short permalink translates to a title/not, and this is based on whether the link is to a *question* or an *answer*. Question-links are automatically reverted to their titles, while answer-links are not (and remain in their `http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/<id>/<user>` form). As an example, here are share/permalinks to

- this question: ["Share" link doesn't really link question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3647/5764)
- this answer: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3648/5764

My way of getting around the no-title answer-links is to use explicit markdown:

```
[<title>](<permalink to answer>)
```

It's slightly more cumbersome and doesn't update with an update of the title of the question, but the presentation is more clear. Regardless of the choice (question or answer, or markdown), a native link should be found in the "Linked to" section of the page. Native here refers to the network. For example, posting a link to a question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) does not automatically grab/translate to the question title:

- Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/914686
- Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/914686
- Markdown: [Why is subtracting these two times (in 1927) giving a strange result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6841333/914686)

---

True, for those interested in so-called "other badges", using the share permalink is the way to go:

[image]

As of now, no native measure exists to track your progress of [these](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/announcer) [announcement](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/58/booster) [badges](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/publicist). I've personally used Google's Short URL service:

[image]

The above link to our [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) via the Google Short URL brings with it [click-statistics](http://goo.gl/z69vm+) by going to `http://goo.gl/z69vm+`.